# Swift UICollectionView works strange, registers only second tap

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I'm implementing a collection view in Xcode 11 project, what happens is that only second tap gets registered. When user taps on left cell it doesn't open detail screen and when user next taps on right cell then left cell opens, very strange behavior. I'm not using storyboards just programmatic approach. Here's my code:

```
let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cv.register(CustomCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    return cv   
}()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myData.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = .white
    cell.data = myData[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let newViewController = SecondViewController(data: myData[indexPath.item])
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SecondViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace ( `didDeselectItemAt` isn't `didSelectItemAt` )

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
```

with

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
```

Also it should be

```
let newViewController = SecondViewController(data: myData[indexPath.item])
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
```